# How to find analytical solutions for systems of equations with user-defined functions incorporating conditional statements

Tags: python, equation, solver

I am trying to use python to numerically solve the system of equations (four equations: eq1 eq2 eq3 and eq4, and four unknowns: T1 T2 T3 T4), which involve user-defined functions that incorporate conditional statements

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sympy import *

Emissivity=0.7

dL = 0.05 #m  #Define the total length of the 1D layer
n = 50   #Define nodal discretisiation   
TambC = 20  #Initial temperature (unit: °C)
TambK = TambC + 273  #Initial temperature (unit: °K)
t_final = 240  #Define final time (unit: minute)

hc = 25
hback = 4

SBCons = 5.67*10**(-8) #Attribute Stefan Boltzmann Constant

dx = L/n #Calculate nodal interval

#Define time interval

dt = 5 #s

#############################################################################
#################Define thermal properties of steel##########################
#############################################################################

#Density of Steel
rho_s = 7800 # Kg/m3


#Specific Heat of Steel

def Cs(Temp):
    
    Temp = Temp - 273
    
    if Temp >= 20 and Temp < 600:
        Cs_Temp = 425 + (7.73 * 10 ** -1) * Temp - (1.69 * 10 ** -3) * Temp ** 2 + (2.22 * 10 ** -6) * Temp ** 3
    elif Temp >= 600 and Temp < 735:
        Cs_Temp = 13002 / (738 - Temp) + 666
    elif Temp >= 735 and Temp < 900:
        Cs_Temp = (17820 / (-731 + Temp)) + 545
    elif Temp >= 900 and Temp < 1200:
        Cs_Temp = 650
 
    return Cs_Temp


#Thermal conductivity of Steel

def Ks(Temp):
    
    Temp = Temp - 273
    
    if Temp >= 20 and Temp < 800:
        Ks_Temp = 54 - 3.33 * 10 ** -2 * Temp
    elif Temp >= 800 and Temp < 1200:
        Ks_Temp = 27.3
 
    return Ks_Temp


#############################################################################
#################Define thermal properties of air############################
#############################################################################

rho_a = 1.225 # Kg/m3
Ka = 0.02 # W/mK
Ca = 1000 # J/KgK

#Define initial condition

TAST1= 294

Temp0 = [293, 293, 293, 293]

T1old = Temp0[0]
T2old = Temp0[1]
T3old = Temp0[2]
T4old = Temp0[3]

T1, T2, T3, T4 = symbols('T1, T2, T3, T4')

eq1 = Eq(Emissivity*SBCons*(TAST1**4-T1**4)+hc*(TAST1-T1), Ks(T1)*(T1-T2)/dx + rho_s*Cs(T1)*dx*(T1-T1old)/dt)
eq2 = Eq(Ks(T1)*(T1-T2)/dx, Ka*(T2-T3)/dL + rho_a*Ca*dL*(T2-T2old)/dt + SBCons/(1/Emissivity+1/Emissivity-1)*(T2**4-T3**4))
eq3 = Eq(T4 - (T3 - (Ka*(T2-T3)/dL - rho_s*Cs(T3)*dx*(T3-T3old)/dt)*dx/Ks(T3)), 0)
eq4 = Eq((Ks(T3)*(T3-T4)/dx - Emissivity*SBCons*(T4**4-Tamb**4) - hback * (T4 - Tamb) - rho_s*Cs(T3)*dx*(T4-T4old)/dt) , 0)

test = nsolve([eq1, eq2, eq3, eq4], [T1, T2, T3, T4], [1,1,1,1] )

print(test)
```

It shows an error,
`TypeError: cannot determine truth value of Relational`, which I can comprehend: the user-defined functions `Ks` and `Cs` contain conditional statements and are dependent on the variables `T1`, `T2` and `T3`. For example:

I just wonder, if numerical solutions aren't straightforward/ available, what are the best solvers to determine the T1, T2, T3 and T4?

Cheers

Yunpeng

Comment: Please provide a [mre] that will allow us to reproduce your problem, and show the __full traceback__ of the error. [Ask] | [question checklist](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/260648/843953). Welcome to Stack Overflow

Comment: @PranavHosangadi my sincere apologies, I am new to this platform and it seems there is a long way to practice how to make my questions more self-explanatory. I have edited my equations to the best I can.

Comment: It's not a good idea to give your return variable the same name as your function.  Consider, if the incoming temp is < 293, then your `Cs` function will return the `Cs` function object, and the `Ks` function will return the `Ks` function object.  You need to have a default value.

Comment: 1. Are you using sympy or some other symbolic math library? Part of making your [mre] is including any imports or libraries you are using. Remember, the easier it is for us to reproduce your problem (ideally by simply copying your code into our environment), the easier it is for us to answer your question 2. Your functions are wrongly indented in your question. Please [format](/help/formatting) your code correctly.

Comment: I have changed my questions again (to address the points as raised by you two above) - thank you for your patience @PranavHosangadi

Comment: Hi @TimRoberts I have varied the name of my variable, so it has now had a different name to the function.

Comment: Your analysis is correct.  You are calling `Ks(T!)` and passing that to the solver, but `T1` doesn't have a value.  I don't know a way around this without running this 8 times, with each combination of `Cs` and `Ks`.

Comment: @TimRoberts many thanks - Since i have invoked the conditional statements, I think I will have to assign an initial value for T1 (and thus T2, T3, T4 based on this initial value of T1). Then solve the system of equations iteratively.

If there is no conditional statement, then Python can solve this system of equations analytically.

Comment: @PranavHosangadi I have clarified again my question - would you be able to have a look? Many thanks :)